# Saving multiple element properties into array with jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, for-loop, position, each

Newbie here! My problem is as follows: I have a dynamically populating ul where each li item contains 5 absolutely positioned inner divs. Like this:

```
<ul id="slider">
 <li class="slide">
   <div class="pic1"></div>
   <div class="pic2"></div>
   <div class="pic3"></div>
   <div class="pic4"></div>
   <div class="pic5"></div>
 </li>
 <li class="slide">
   <div class="pic1"></div>
   <div class="pic2"></div>
   <div class="pic3"></div>
   <div class="pic4"></div>
   <div class="pic5"></div>
 </li>
 //more li items...
</ul>
```

Each one of these absolutely positioned divs uses a sibling's height to calculate its final position with jQuery. The horizontal (left, right) properties are applied directly through css. I tried using the each method for each pic class to set the css, like these examples:

```
var pic2 = new Array();
$('.slide .pic2').each(function(i) {
    pic2.push($(this).siblings('.pic1').find('img').height(); 
    $(this).css({ top : pic2[i] + 10 });
});

var pic4 = new Array();
$('.slide .pic4').each(function(i) {
    pic4.push($(this).siblings('.pic3').find('img').height(); 
    $(this).css({ top : pic4[i] + 10 });
});
```

But I think there must be a simpler, more compact way to do this, as this seems like too complicated and also it breaks in IE7 and IE8, I noticed. Maybe a for loop for example that will create a multidimensional array and will apply the css to each item according to certain if statements, or perhaps using the .position method? Any ideas? Thank you!

---- Edit to add Answer for Future newbies like myself:

Using Shasteriskt's answer I was able to streamline my ugly each functions and also add certain parameters according to class, like this:

```
$('.slider li').children('div').each(function(i,picItem){
       if ( $(this).hasClass('pic2') ) {
            var top = $(picItem).prev().find('img').height();
            $(picItem).css({top: top + 100});
       }
      if ( $(this).hasClass('pic5') ) {
            var top = $(picItem).prev().find('img').height();
            $(picItem).css({top: top + 60});
       }
      else {
           var top = $(picItem).prev().find('img').height();
           $(picItem).css({top: top + 10});
      }
   });
```

Thank you, Shasteriskt! Lots of chocolate cookies for you! :)

Comment: why not just let css position the elements without any js? for example : `.slide div {margin-top : 10px;}`

Comment: Because the grid design I'm using is very specific, hence the absolute positioning based on the divs' heights and widths. Though now that you say that, makes me wonder if I did try that or not! lol Let me check and I'll tell you ;)

Comment: I know that you probably have a strict grid but since you didn't specify that in your question I thought I gave it a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any reason why you need to push each value into the array? Unless you need to use it after, I don't think you really need it.

You can streamline this as follows:

```
   $('.slider li').children('div:odd').each(function(i,picItem){
       var top = $(picItem).prev().find('img').height();
       $(picItem).css({top: top + 10});
   });
```

Comment: This actually kinda works! The only thing is that, like I told Gion above, my grid is of a very specific design, so certain items top position varies not according the div immediately on top of it, but the one next to it... (all divs have different widths set with css, what changes is the order on the grid according to height). Is it possible to add different if statements to what you posted, say something like, "if this is pic3 then picitem.css is top + 80" ? I'm sorry if this question is silly, I'm new to jQuery so I'm just now teaching myself to do pretty things with it O:)

Comment: You can check by doing `if($(picItem).hasClass('.pic2')){ //do something }` to check which div is currently in the loop.